# Unable to create auto refresh view with Epoch date conversion to date in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

When I'm trying to convert epoch date(e.g. 1589889600000) to a date format(e.g. 05/19/2020) in redshift(using this TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + column_with_time_in_ms/1000 *INTERVAL '1 second'), I am able to do it but when I'm embedding that query and trying to create a auto refresh materialized view then it is giving error saying " materialized view cannot be created, reason: auto refresh is not supported for materialized view with mutable function. Found mutable function :text.;

Comment: How are you obtaining the timestamp?  I'm guessing you are using a function?  BTW, I advise materialized views should never be used.  They have no advantages, but prevent you from selecting column encodings.

Answer (score 1):

datetime functions are not supported for incremental auto refresh, unfortunately.

> Limitations for incremental refresh
> ...
> Mutable functions, such as date-time functions, RANDOM and non-STABLE user-defined functions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/materialized-view-refresh-sql-command.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I faced a similar issue today and was stuck for very long. Should have read the link before trying other timestamp solutions.